# Share Anglar2 codebase between web app and hybrid app

Tags: angular, ionic2, nativescript

I want to create an mobile app based on my existing Angular2 web app codebase. For my understanding there is two options of doing so which is Ionic2 and NativeScript.

I looked in to both and I see at least one problem - it is seams to be both of them have their own specific UI elements so I cant just take my codebase and wrap it somehow with Ionic2 or NativeScript. Also I discovered that Ionic2 does not support Component Router so in that case I would need to implement my routing using Ionic2 NavigationCompenent, etc.

May be someone already done something like that and can share some thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak much on ionic but people are doing it with NativeScript, here is one seed project to get started with https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced . Both frameworks are going to come with pros/cons. If you really want to share all of your app with mobile and web ionic is your easiest option because it's all web based whereas NativeScript uses native ui rendering so the ui cannot be the same as the web, however with the seed setup most of your logic/services are shared and you only need to implement the ui for both. Some work has been done on the idea of using one markup file for native ui and web DOM but it's difficult to map a good native ui to a web ui that scales for all screens. I imagine it will definitely be a thing in the future but right now I've not seen much on this specific topic. Another benefit of ionic is their PWA support they've added recently. You should probably give both a quick try at a small app and see how you like the shared logic, etc and what gives you the best outcome.